# .NET Universe Poster

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core

Sometime ago, Microsoft releases a [.NET Universe Poster](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=39952) showing the main .NET SDKs, libraries classified by its type and platform. This was a valuable assets for most of us to consolidate our understanding around **.NET world**.

[image: Universe]

I have been in search of similar and up to date poster for few days. But no luck so far.

**Question is:** Can you propose an up-to-date poster with recent offering and changes ? I presume, this will help all of us to find missing pieces in our understanding around new Microsoft offering in the area of **.NET**.

Comment: I only know [this VS2017 poster](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2017/03/VisualStudio2017_ProductLaunchPoster-1.png)

Comment: I suspect, that any such poster today would be woefully incomplete given the huge explosion of technologies over the last few years.  I don't think it would be possible to have any kind of accurate summary poster that would fit on anything less than an entire wall.  What's more, VS is shipped iteratively now, and any such poster would likely be out of date within weeks or months.  VS used to only be updated once every 1-3 years, so such posters were better investments.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, Very true. However, it would be ideal to have some to make things clear in our head. Sorry, I just started to grab recent changes from Microsoft.

Comment: @magicandre1981, Thank You. Your reference was really valuable for VS IDE 2017 and it capabilities. But I am up for something different. Much appreciate your help.

Comment: that's why I said, only for VS2017. I can't find anything related to .net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not a poster as such, I suspect what you're looking for would be .Net Standard?

[image: .Net Standard]

introduced here [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/)
 Project page here [link](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/netstandard-20/README.md)

Answer (score 1):

There is a 2014 version published by Microsoft. More updated version will be nice but you can at least use the update.

[.NET Universe Poster 2014 at MS Download Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44228)

Answer (score 1):

[image: The .NET Universe]

I think this was the most recent universe poster by the time of 2017.
It consists of .NET related aspects like `IoT`, `Azure`, `UWP`, ...

[source](https://web.archive.org/web/20170718220555/https://www.microsoft.com/net/images/dotNET_poster.pdf)

Comment: @Dharman Since the source is not available anymore, I am not able to link the correct source. I have added a reference to an archived version.

Comment: The archive link did not work. I changed it to http
https://web.archive.org/web/20170718220555/ttp://www.microsoft.com/net/images/dotNET_poster.pdf